# Why does the Rust borrow checker reject this function?

Tags: rust

This (very silly) function fails to compile:

```
fn silliness(mut z: &mut int) {
    z = &mut *z;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
$ rustc blah.rs 
blah.rs:2:5: 2:16 error: cannot assign to `z` because it is borrowed
blah.rs:2     z = &mut *z;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
blah.rs:2:14: 2:16 note: borrow of `z` occurs here
blah.rs:2     z = &mut *z;
                       ^~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

It seems to me that since there's only one reference to what z's pointing to at any time, things should be okay. What don't I understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe, but the compiler is just not quite smart enough to understand it yet. The following perturbation compiles fine:

```
fn silliness(mut z: &mut int) {
    let tmp = z;
    z = &mut *tmp;
}

fn main() {}
```

[playpen](http://play.rust-lang.org/?run=1&code=fn%20silliness%28mut%20z%3A%20%26mut%20int%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20tmp%20%3D%20z%3B%0A%20%20%20%20z%20%3D%20%26mut%20*tmp%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%7D)

This introduce-a-temporary trick is a useful tool especially when writing loops that traverse data structures to which you have a `&mut` reference, e.g. [`TreeMap`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/5e834243b6837a2386d623e1d546a3d25057b8f5/src/libcollections/treemap.rs#L1490-L1507) uses it (the `let temp`) for `find_mut`, which uses a loop for efficiency (instead of the obvious implementation via recursion, which doesn't need this trick).

Comment: I don't think this is about the compiler not being smart enough. `&mut *z` *has* to make the compiler consider `z` being uniquely borrowed because that's the only way to prevent aliasing. Otherwise, you'd have two usable and mutable references to the same memory location: the original `z` and the result of `&mut *z`. The only reason why this could be considered "ok" is that this aliasing only exists for a short time. But as far as I'm concerned, even this short time is too long and should not make compiler devs come up with special rules for checking the innocence of short-time aliasing.

Comment: @sellibitze, it *is* not smart enough: [#10520](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/10520). The compiler can perfectly well be taught to understand that reassigning `z` is like having the temporary (i.e. as if `z` was "moved out" just before the reassignment).

Comment: (The aliasing happens a lot, and is fine: it is OK to have pointer values that are the same--i.e. aliasing at the machine level--as long as only one path is usable, which is what the compiler enforces.)